# Laravel task scheduler doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, queue, laravel-5.3, laravel-scheduler

I tried to run scheduler in laravel 5.3 with the following code in `App/Console/Kernel.php`

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('queue:work')->everyMinute()->withoutOverlapping();
}
```

and set cron jobs in my shared hosting with the following:

```
* * * * * php /home/username/public_html/laravel/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

but it doesn't work in my shared hosting

I used database driver for my queue, and the attempts still 0, which is the queue is not execute by the task scheduler.

Anyone can help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things you might want to check:

**queue:work**

> Note that once the queue:work command has started, it will continue to
>   run until it is manually stopped or you close your terminal.
>   https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queues#running-the-queue-worker

Are you sure you want to spawn a new process with the Scheduler every minute?

**powering scheduler**

artisan schedule:run command needs to be run every minute in order for the Scheduler to work. This might be done with the cron: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scheduling#introduction

Comment: Sorry, i'm not explanied yet that I've set the cron jobs with I've set the cron jobs, every minute "* * * * * php /home/username/public_html/laravel/artisan schedule:run > /dev/null 2>&1"

Comment: So does the Scheduler work in your local environment? Also, write your own simple command which logs something and try to schedule it.

Answer (score 0):

This link might be helpful to setup scheduler. I have done with this.Please try.

https://www.sitepoint.com/managing-cronjobs-with-laravel/

Answer (score 0):

I use shared hosting on A2hosting and the command that works for me is

```
nohup php artisan queue:work &
```

The & assures the command keeps running and with nohup the process won't be killed even if you exit or close the terminal.

UPDATE:
If you can run shell commands from PHP, this is the solution I have eventually implemented. After 3 days it works as expected. Only one instance of `queue:work` runs and it only restarts when it stopped running. The schedule is running every minute.

```
if ( ! strstr(shell_exec('ps xf'), 'php artisan queue:work'))
    {
        $schedule->command('queue:work')->everyMinute();
    }
```

You may also search on `queue:work` instead of `php artisan queue:work`. Run `shell_exec('ps xf')` in tinker and see what you get.